# apache2 virtualhost configuration with two subdirectories

Tags: apache, redirect, virtualhost

I'm running Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 server. It's purpose is a mail server so it has postfix, dovecot and roundcube on it (amongst other things). I'm trying, and failing, to configure Apache to serve the pages that I want.

I have an SSL certificate installed and working correctly. I want to force all access over HTTPS so I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect / https://mailserver.hni.ae/
</VirtualHost>
```

Both sets of files to be served are under `/var/www/html`, the first being `/var/www/html/A` and the other `/var/www/html/B` (let's say).  I have configured my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` (which has a symlink to `./sites-enabled`) to be:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/private/mycert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/mycert.key

    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory /var/www/html/A>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/B>
      Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Order Deny,Allow
       Deny from All
       Allow from 192.168.1.1
    </Directory>

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And that works.  I can go to `www.mydomain.com/B` and it serves the login page for those pages (only when I access from the specified IP address), and `www.mydomain.com/A` and login to the pages from app A.

My problem: I want to be able to go to `www.mydomain.com/C` and just plain `www.mydomain.com` and be redirected to `www.mydomain.com/A` but when I use `Redirect ...` the server gets into a loop and tries to serve `www.mydomain.com/AAAAAAA...`.  I suspect I should use the `RedirectMatch temp ^/$...` directive but can't get that to work either.  Maybe something to do with the `Redirect` for `:80` to `:443` clashing?  There is no `.htaccess` involved as I'm using `AllowOverride None`.

I've read the Apache 2.4 documentation thoroughly but just can't figure it out.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `RewriteRule`. Add this to your VirtualHost:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(C/?|)$ /A [R,L]
```

Make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled too.

Explanation:
Regex `^/(C/?|)$` will match `/C` optionally followed by a `/`, or just `/` i.e. the root of www.mydomain.com

Comment: That worked perfectly @arco444, thank you!  Time to go and read up on this on apache.org so I understand how it works :)  Appreciated!